# Using java.io.Serializable when implementing a tree?

Tags: java, serialization, tree

I have ANOTHER serialization question, but this time it is in regards to Java's native serialization import when serializing to binary.  I have to serialize a random tree that is generated in another java file.  I know how serialization and deserialization works, but the example I followed when using binary serialization with java.io.Serializable did not work in the same fashion as when I did it with, say a simple object.  Here is my code segment:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class BinaryS 
    {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tree randomTree = RandomTreeBuilder.randomTree(10);

        FileOutputStream fOut=null;
        ObjectOutputStream oOut=null;

        try{
            fOut= new FileOutputStream("/Users/Pat/programs/binaryfile.txt");
            oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
            oOut.writeObject(randomTree); //serializing randomTree
            System.out.println("An employee is serialized into /Users/Pat/binaryfile.txt");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                oOut.flush();
                oOut.close();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I believe the problem is when I use writeObject(randomTree).  I get some terminal exceptions when this happens... they are below:

java.io.NotSerializableException: GeneralTree
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1081)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:302)
    at BinaryS.main(BinaryS.java:24)

edit:  I know it says GeneralTree, but at the start of the class it was in I put

```
print("public class RandomTreeBuilder implements java.io.Serializable");
```

then, GeneralTree is found below it

```
print(" protected static Tree tree;
protected static ArrayList names;
//e6.1

/**
 *Builds a random tree.  The build method does the work.
 */
//b6.2
public static Tree randomTree(int n) {
    // Create a random binary tree with n external nodes
    tree = new GeneralTree();
    names = NameGenerator.getNames();
    build(tree.getRoot(), n);  // auxiliary recursive method
    return tree;
```

");

Update:  Hey guys, I figured out my own problem, turns out I am an idiot and didn't realize I had to download an additional .java file, an easy fix now!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

At a guess, GeneralTree doesn't implement the [Serializable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) marker interface, as documented [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)).

Actually, it could also be the objects you're storing in the tree aren't Serializable.  A Collection is only serializable if all the elements in it are as well.

Answer (score 0):

> edit: I know it says GeneralTree, but
>   at the start of the class it was in I
>   put

```
print("public class RandomTreeBuilder implements java.io.Serializable");
```

This does you no good - you are not trying to write an object of type *RandomTreeBuilder* to the object stream; the type you are trying to write is *GeneralTree* and it is that class that must implement *Serializable*.

---

FYI: in case you haven't come across it, this article covers many of the tricks and caveats of serialization: [Discover the secrets of the Java Serialization API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/).